# Why was Anomander Rake not released when the sword was shattered?

Tags: malazan

I just finished reading book 10 of the Malazan Book of the Fallen and I was left with a big question from books 8-10. Major spoilers below.

> When Dragnipur is shattered by Caladan Brood, it released all the beings trapped within that weren't killed by the forces of chaos (or already died within the sword). Apsalara, Draconus, Hood and the Bridgeburners were all released.

**Why is it that Anomander Rake was not released when the sword was shattered?**

Comment: ah malazan, another question that the books just forget to answer. better luck in future novels. lol

Comment: @Himarm only the books do answer this.

Comment: Spoilers in the title muchl?

Comment: There have been two horrible spoilers in question titles in SFFSE in recent weeks, and both have been questions about *The Malazan Book of the Fallen*. It's extremely galling for this to happen when one is less than halfway through reading the second in a sequence of ten very long novels.

Comment: Sorry, my original title was edited for being too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Malazan Wiki](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Anomander_Rake) has the answer and summarizes what is written in Toll the hounds Chapter 24:

> Once inside Dragnipur, he sacrificed himself to bring Mother Dark and the Gate of Darkness back to the Tiste Andii in Black Coral. The sacrifice dispersed Rake's soul into Kurald Galain, and earned Draconus's forgiveness and respect.